# re.sub isn't matching when it seems it should

Tags: python, regex

any help as to why this regex isnt' matching`<td>\n` etc? i tested it successfully on pythex.org. Basically i'm just trying to clean up the output so it just says `myfile.doc`.  I also tried `(<td>)?\\n\s+(</td>)?`

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> import re
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(open("/home/user/message_tracking.html"), "html.parser")
>>> 
>>> filename = str(soup.findAll("td", text=re.compile(r"\.[a-z]{3,}")))
>>> print filename
[<td>\n                  myfile.doc\n                </td>]
>>> duh = re.sub("(<td>)?\n\s+(</td>)?", '', filename)
>>> print duh
[<td>\n                  myfile.doc\n                </td>]
```

Comment: What are you trying to match to?

Comment: will update post. sec

Comment: Can you simplify this so that it doesn't involve `BeautifulSoup`? Just assign `filename` to a string literal, so we can easily run your code ourselves and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the `repr(filename)`, but I think your problem is the confusing of real newline characters with escaped newline characters.

Compare and contrast the examples below:

```
>>> pattern = "(<td>)?\n\s+(</td>)?"
>>> filename1 =  '[<td>\n                  myfile.doc\n                </td>]'
>>> filename2 = r'[<td>\n                  myfile.doc\n                </td>]'
>>>
>>> re.sub(pattern, '', filename1)
'[myfile.doc]'
>>> re.sub(pattern, '', filename2)
'[<td>\\n                  myfile.doc\\n                </td>]'
```

Comment: didn't know about repr(). very useful! there were additional backslashes: >>> repr(filename)
"'[<td>\\\\n                  filename.doc\\\\n                </td>]'"

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to just get the stripped string from within the `<td>` tag you can just let BeautifulSoup do it for you by getting the `stripped_strings` attribute of a tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("/home/user/message_tracking.html"),"html.parser")
filename_tag = soup.find("td", text=re.compile(r"\.[a-z]{3,}"))) #finds the first td string in the html with specified text
filename_string = filename_tag.stripped_strings
print filename_string
```

If you want to extract further strings from tags of the same type you can then use `findNext` to extract the next td tag after the current one:

```
filename_tag = soup.findNext("td", text=re.compile(r"\.[a-z]{3,}"))) #finds the next td string in the html with specified text after current one
filename_string = filename_tag.stripped_strings
print filename_string
```

And then loop through...